# Solspace Importer not splitting matrix fields from CSV file?

Tags: matrix, solspace, solspace-importer, csv

I'm currently trying to import a CSV file using Solspace Importer, and I've mostly gotten my issues worked out. However, I have a column in my csv that needs to be imported into a Matrix field consisting of two Text fields (one required). According to the Solspace docs here:

http://www.solspace.com/docs/importer/third_party_support/#pt_matrix

I should be able to wrap my values and comma separate them like so:

```
"Column1Row1","Column1Row2","Column1Row3"
```

But this just imports one row into the Matrix field with the value "Column1Row","Column1Row2","Column1Row3" for the first column. At first I thought it was a parse issue, so I made sure to have my CSV files enclosed in single quotes and use that as the encloser for the import profile, so this segment of the CSV looks like this:

```
...,'column before matrix column','"Column1Row1","Column1Row2","Column1Row3"','column after matrix column',...
```

But that doesn't work either. I've tried a myriad of enclosers and quotation depth, as well as various escapements, but it always takes the entire column in as one row. My data is coming from someone who can't use anything but Excel, and his data already required 100's of lines of macro to get right, so trying to interchange to a different data-type and formatting my columns and... well, this is why we want to use a utility like Importer. Does anyone know what CSV format Importer requires to parse into a Matrix field??

Comment: What version of EE and Importer are you using? Also, given that CSV files are one-dimensional, `"Column1","Column2","Column3"` should import in three of Matrix's columns and in *one row* (assuming you assigned `Column1`, `Column2` and `Column3` to three Matrix columns in Importer). You can't import multiple Matrix rows for an entry using a CSV file. XML/JSON are suited for that.

Comment: Having `"Column1","Column2","Column3"` in not only one row, but also one _column_ is odd, however. Do you have a screenshot of your import profile setup, in particular for your Matrix field?

Comment: Hmm, honestly I think the example on your site is a little confusing. Having the CSV/XML/JSON examples together with no comment made me assume a single row field could represent Matrix columns AND rows for all three examples, but it's really just XML/JSON that can import with those extra dimensions in a single field. I appreciate your support, but I'll have to find another way to handle it I guess. Perhaps I'll look into CSV->JSON conversion libraries and script something to vertically and horizontally parse a single CSV row into 2d JSON. New feature request?

Comment: Yes, that would be an FR. You can file one here under the Importer section, if it's not already requested, in which case you can add your +1: http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions